# Pods getting scheduled irrespective of insufficient resources

Tags: kubernetes

Upon submitting few jobs (say, 50) targeted on a single node, I am getting pod status as "OutOfpods" for few jobs. I have reduced the maximum number of pods on this worker node to "10", but still observe above issue.
Kubelet configuration is default with no changes.

kubernetes version: v1.22.1

- Worker Node

Os: CentOs 7.9
memory: 528 GB
CPU: 40 cores

kubectl describe pod :

> Warning  OutOfpods  72s   kubelet            Node didn't have enough resource: pods, requested: 1, used: 10, capacity: 10

Comment: What kubernetes distribution are you running (e.g. minikube)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @Alejandro703, I have installed kubernetes cluster using kubeadm.

Comment: The problem is that kubernetes is not scheduling the queued pods properly as it should ideally do. Upon submission of jobs, few jobs (can be pending or runnning) go to "OutOfPods" status without getting properly scheduled. Seems like scheduler is trying to forcefully schedule it even if the resource requests are not met. Expected scheduler behavior should be to keep pod in pending state until the resource gets actually freed up after completion of running jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized this to be a known issue for kubelet v1.22 as confirmed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/104560). The fix will be reflected in the next latest release.

Simple resolution here is to downgrade kubernetes to v1.21.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this problem as well w/ K8s v1.22. I'm scheduling around 100 containers w/ one node with an extended resource called "executors" and a capacity of 300 per node. Each container requests 10. The pods stay pending for a long time, but as soon as they are assigned by the scheduler, kubelet on the node says its out of resource. Its just a warning I suppose, but it actually leads to "failed" status on the pod atleast briefly. I have to check whether its re-created as pending or not.

````
  Normal   Scheduled               40m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned ci-smoke/userbench-4a306d7-l1all-8zv7n-3803535768 to sb-bld-srv-39
  Warning  OutOfwdc.com/executors  40m   kubelet            Node didn't have enough resource:wdc.com/executors, requested: 10, used: 300, capacity: 300```
````